# How to build periodically on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cron

I want to know how to build periodically on Jenkins. For now, I have `H 17 * * 1-5`. My job builds at 17h every weekday, but I want it to build 3-4 times in the same night. For example : 1. 17h 2. 18h 3. 19h ... I'm not sure to understand the syntax of cron. Can someone help me ? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not know why you want it but the following should work:

```
H 17,18,19 * * 1-5
```

Comment: To test the stability of my job. Thx :)